# ZF2 Module API - What structure and classes?

Tags: php, api, architecture, module, zend-framework2

I'm building an web shop with Zend Framework 2 and this web shop will work with an API which the supplier provides.

We want to sell custom car products like air intakes, air suspension parts & kits, body kits, exhausts, grilles, steering wheels, etc.

The supplier offers an API(just `GET` calls with params and comma-separated responses) with the following functions

- **Products**

  - Search by category;
  - Search by car brand --> model --> type;
  - Search by id;
  - Search by name;
- **Orders**

  - Add;
  - View;
  - Delete.
- **Invoices**

  - View;
- **Stock** get the current values
- **Delivery** view current status by orderId.

I have build a module called **SupplierName**.
I have created a Module.php file:

```
<?php
/**
* This file is placed here for compatibility with ZendFramework 2's ModuleManager.
* It allows usage of this module even without composer.
* The original Module.php is in 'src/SupplierName/Module.php' in order to
* respect the PSR-0 convention
*/
require_once __DIR__ . '/src/SupplierName/Module.php';
```

**vendor/SupplierName/src/SupplierName/Module.php**

```
<?php

namespace SupplierName;

class Module
{
    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/../../config/module.config.php';
    }

    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

In the indexAction of my IndexController of the main module I use the code beneath to load my module.

```
$supplierNameClient = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('SupplierName\Client');
```

And now my problem comes... This is the first time I'll be building a module which only will be used to load data from an external resource and pass it on to my own system. The problem is that I did not manage to think of a good structure of my module...
I think there should be a class for every product type(grill, exhaust, steeringWheel, etc), order, invoice, etc.

I've been searching and looked at http://modules.zendframework.com/page/2?query=api. There's a list with modules which should be used to communicate with a webservice.

Could anyone tell me where to look for information / samples to build a module like this?
Or could anyone give me an example how I should structure this module?

Many thanks in advance and if something is unclear, please let me know so I can explain it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I would approach this is to create an entity class for each product type. These are simple PHP classes with properties and relevant methods that represent the product. e.g.

```php
namespace SupplierName\Entity;

class SteeringWheel
{
    protected $diameter;

    public function getDiameter()
    {
        return $this->diameter;
    }

    public function setDiameter($diameter)
    {
        $this->diameter = $diameter;
        return $this;
    }

}
```

To fetch these entities, I would use a mapper class that talks to the external. e.g.

```php
namespace SupplierName\Mapper;

class SteeringWheelMapper extends AbstractWebServiceMapper
{
    public function fetchbyDiameter($diameter) {
        // construct search query and then call up a parent
        // class method that calls the vendor's webservice
        // that presumably returns an array of data.
        //
        // Within this method, convert that array of data into a
        // set of SteeringWheel objects and return.
    }
}
```

The common code for talking to the external resource is stored in `AbstractVendorWebServiceMapper` (and maybe supporting classes), with the specialisation of `SteeringWheelMapper` dealing solely with steering wheels and creating `SteeringWheel` entities.

I would then probably add an `EventManager` to the mapper so that I could set up events and listeners to cache the data from the vendor's web service.

Comment: Thank you, Rob!
When I want to show steering wheels, the API wants a brand name, series name and model name. I can call the https://apiurl.com/steering-wheels/car-brand-list. That URL gives me a list of car brands. Should I just create a method within the SteeringWheelMapper and return an array? Is that the way to do it?

Comment: I'd like to use \Zend\Http\Client for the HTTP calls. I have created a file in vendor/SupplierName/src/Suppliername/Mapper/AbstractWebServiceMapper. Should I inject a var with an instance of \Zend\Http\Client into AbstractWebServiceMapper and let Suppliername\Mapper\SteeringWheelMapper extend Suppliername\Mapper\AbstrachtWebServicemapper? Just checkin' if I properly understand your idea...

Comment: That's what I'd do, yes. Inject a configured `Client` via ServiceManager.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to accept your answers, but to those of you who think about it different, please let me know!